# Is there way to get position independent code when linker doesn't support -pie option

Tags: gcc, gnu, ld, qemu, riscv

Emulator: Qemu

Architecture : riscv64

Operating System : Not Applicable (Baremetal)

I am loading firmware at one location lets that be 0x50000000. I have provided memory layout in linker script.

I am compiling/loading another program (which doesn't have main) without c start routines and loading at another location 0x60000000. In the linker script I am **not** providing any memory layout.

I am calling that program from firmware through function pointer pointing to program address i.e. 0x60000000.

Its getting called, but when printing address of any math functions or any other global or local static variables, it printing the offset but not the absolute address.

Here offset I mean address relative to 0x60000000 eg: offset d0 means -> absolute 0x600000d0

How to get that???

```
target_compile_options(${BASENAME}.o PRIVATE "-pie")
target_link_libraries(${BASENAME}.o PRIVATE "-fPIE -nostartfiles -flto -T ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/linker.lds")
```

I have tried compile options -fPIC, -fpic, -pie, and in linker -fPIE.
I can't use -pie flag to linker in my case as It is not supported by our riscv tool chain.

Note: When I am adding -mno-relax flag its working as I expected and I am able to access absolute addresses. But I do not want to use it as I need to reduce code. And I am not sure why its working.

for function program you can refer to
[Not able to print the absolute address of global variable address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76603660/not-able-to-print-the-absolute-address-of-global-variable-address/76603698)